# Expected value of a multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, multinomial-distribution

A multinomial distribution can be given as

$ M(m_1,\dots,m_K|N,P) =  {N \choose m_1\dots m_K}\prod_k p_k^{m_k} $

The expected value is $Np_k$.

How can I prove it?

Comment: Do you mean that the expected value is $NP$? I'm having difficulty understanding your notation.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me: it looks like it specifies a distribution for a vector-valued random variable, whence its expectation must be a vector, while "np" (whatever it might be) appears to be a number. Could you please clarify your notation and the question?

Comment: Mean of Multinomial distribution is $NP_k$ not $NP$

Comment: try for $k=2$ you get the idea

Comment: @Azeem "$NP_k$" makes no sense because $k$ has not been defined.

Comment: @whuber Agreed. If I've understood it rightly, I think the question might be rephrased to say there are $K$ random variables, i.e. $X_i$, $i \in [1,K]$, where $X_i$ represents the number of occurrences of item $i$ in a choice of $N$ items, with entry $i$ in the vector of probabilities $\mathrm{P}$, $\mathrm{P}_i$ giving the probability of drawing item $i$. The probability of selecting $m_1$ of item $1\ldots m_K$ of item $K$ is then given by $M$. The **expected value** in question, is, I believe, $E(X_i)=NP_i$, which is equivalent to a binomial expectation, with $n=N$, $p=P_i$.

Comment: @TooTone Thanks: in other words, you propose that the expectation of this *vector-valued* random variable should be written $(Np_1, Np_2, \ldots, Np_K)$. Please note--because several of the comments appearing here are otherwise misleading--that the OP distinguishes capital letters from small letters ("$k$" and "$K$" have obviously different meanings in the question), whence we shouldn't immediately assume (say) that "$n$" and "$N$" mean the same thing, nor that "$P_i$" and "$p_i$" are identical.

Comment: @whuber thanks I think that's a better way of putting it. I did think of writing $NP$ but I couldn't find a way of expressing an element-wise product nicely. You're right that the OP should clarify; it's not a very useful question otherwise.

Comment: **Related thread:** the entire moment generating function for multinomial distributions is obtained at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61697/moment-generating-function-of-multinomial-distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I understood it. The expected value should be $Np_k$ for expecting the state k over N draws. But I have no idea about how to prove it using equations e.g. $E(x)=∑_i x_ip(x_i)$ etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A demonstration using "equations" was requested in a comment.  Here is a short, simple one that is practically painless.

#### Notation and definitions

Let the random $K$-vector $X$ have a multinomial distribution with parameters $\mathbb p = (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_K)$.  This means that $p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_K=1$, $0 \le p_i$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, K$, and the probability that $X = (m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_K) = \mathbb m$ is given by

$$\Pr(X=\mathbb m) =\binom{N}{\mathbb m}\mathbb p^\mathbb m$$

In this shorthand notation $\binom{N}{\mathbb m} = N!/(m_1! m_2! \ldots m_K!)$ is a multinomial coefficient (which is nonzero only when all the $m_i$ are natural numbers and sum to $N \ge 1$) and $\mathbb p ^ \mathbb m = p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\cdots p_K^{m_k}.$

By definition, the expectation of $X$ is the *vector*

$$\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{\mathbb m} \Pr(X = \mathbb m)\mathbb m =\sum_{\mathbb m} \binom{N}{\mathbb m}\mathbb p^\mathbb m \mathbb m$$

where the sum extends over the (finite number of) values of $\mathbb m$ for which the probability is nonzero.

#### Solution

By expanding the sum using the definition of the multinomial coefficients, notice that

$$1 = 1^N = (p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_K)^N = \sum_{\mathbb m}\binom{N}{\mathbb m}\mathbb p^\mathbb m.$$

Viewing the $p_i$ as variables, we can recognize the component terms $\binom{N}{\mathbb m}\mathbb p^\mathbb m m_i$ in the expectation as the result of applying the differential operator $p_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$ to the right hand side, because $p_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \left(p_i^{m_i}\right) = m_i p_i^{m_i}.$  Another way to compute the same thing is to use the Chain Rule to differentiate the penultimate term in the preceding multinomial expansion:

$$p_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}(p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_K)^N = p_iN(p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_K)^{N-1}\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial p_i} = Np_i(1)^{N-1} = Np_i.$$

Therefore

$$\mathbb E[X] = (Np_1, Np_2, \ldots, Np_K),$$

*QED*.

Comment: Its also worthwhile to point out that the $p_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$ trick works for higher order moments as well.  For example $\left(p_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}\right)^2=p_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}m_ip_i^{m_i}=m_i^2p_i^{m_i}$ and so on by replacing "2" with $k$ gives you the $k$th order moment $E[m_i^k]$

Comment: @probabilityislogic, so to find out $E(X)$ is equivalent to compute the expectation for each $m_i$, which holds all the other $m_j$ constant?

Comment: @loganecolss - this is correct.  Note that $ m_j $ is a constant, and not a random variable (compound distributions aside)

Answer (score 4):

I think that you mean that you take $N$ draws from a multinomial distribution and the expected value of getting object $k$ is $Np_k$. The easiest way to show this is to reduce the problem to $N$ draws from a binomial distribution, with the options "not get object $k$" and "get object $k$." Consider $K$ of these separate binomial problems and you get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I prove it using equations e.g. $E(x)=\sum xp(x)$ etc.

Comment: $E(x)=\sum_i x_ip(x_i)$

Comment: @user570593, building on Charlie's hint to analyze the number of type $k$ as a binomial random variable with $N$ trials and success probability $p_k$, I suggest you write out, in terms of the binomial probability mass function, what that expectation is. It's a bit involved but with a little algebra and the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), you can get your answer.

Comment: Thank you. The answer is here. http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Binomial_Distribution