# Is it possible for a multinomial sample to be a single number?

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, notation, topic-models

I'm reading the Latent Dirichlet Allocation paper trying to understand it. However I got stuck at the very first part! When they sampled from a multinomial distribution and considered the result to be a single number! My understanding if the multinomial distribution is to return a vector where the number of its elements are the same as the number of probability vector parameter plugged into the multinomial.

I'm not sure if I misunderstood the notation.

**EDIT:**
Consider Q is a probability vector of size K. Z must be a scalar from 1 to K. But I don't understand how is that achieved from the notation of Z ~ multi(Q)

Here is the link to the paper (page 4): http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: $Z$ is in fact a scalar. In this case, an integer from $1$ to $K$, corresponding to the $z^{th}$ topic. Sampling from that multinomial distribution is analogous to rolling a die with $K$ sides. It is perhaps more appropriate to call this a *categorical* distribution rather than a multinomial, but they are equivalent when considering draws with only one outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say that each trial has three possible outcomes in the typical multinomial experiment, with success probabilities $(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)$.

Let's play this multinomial experiment once (in `R`; see [?rmultinom](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Multinom.html)):

```
> rmultinom(n=1, size=1, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2))
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    1
```

The third outcome occurred, which is your "single number''.

Let's play again

```
> rmultinom(n=1, size=1, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2))
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    0
[3,]    0
```

Now the first outcome occurred.

Answer (score -1):

A multinomial distribution is the distribution of the number of successes out of $k$ independent binomial trials whereby the probability of success in each trial is fixed at $p$. So the outcome is not a vector but a scalar (for example, 3 successes).

Comment: I don't really understand it. A multinomial distribution accepts a vector of scalars (let's say [3, 1, 5], where each scalar is the number of successes of a category) and returns the probability that this combination of successes happen. So if I sample from such a distribution I should get a vector [k1,k2,k3].  I am true?

Comment: This description of a *general* multinomial distribution appears to conflict with standard definitions, such as the one on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), or with the use of this distribution here on CV, such as in my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66365/expected-value-of-a-multinomial-distribution/66380#66380.